# how to use a command of a bash script in a expect script?

Tags: bash, expect

I have the following code, which is an expect script, 
I want to use mkdir to create a directory called input
but I know that the command mkdir doesnt work in an 
expect script I would appreciate any help with this 
issue, I tried the folloging approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
 expect "hello"
 send "world"
 mkdir input
```

Comment: `Expect` is based on `TCL`, and it has a `mkdir` function: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/file.htm#M22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `bash`, just use TCL's built-in [`file mkdir`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/file.htm#M22) command:

```
file mkdir input
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, but I have one question more what is the diference if I use exec instead of file?

Comment: I have one question more mkdir is already integrated in any version of TCL or what is exactly TCL?

Comment: I assume it is. You should check the documentation for your version to make sure.